# Jquery resizeabale increase height by a particular value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resize

I have a Jquery resizable element. What i would like to do is, increase or decrease its height by a particular value. Say, increase 100px, on each increase or decrease by the same. I know i can do it with callback functions, and setting the values manually. is there any other way than this?

```
$( "#draggable" ).resizable({handles: 's'});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/k_rma/74EG8/)

```js
$( "#draggable" ).resizable({
    handles: 's',
    resize: function(e, ui)
    {
        // Resize with increments of 100px
        var newH = Math.ceil((e.clientY - $(this).offset().top)/100)*100;
        $(this).height(newH);
    }
});
```